# flutter - Widget keeps rebuilding everytime there's a new item added

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, rebuild

I'm making a chat app using firestore and the widget keeps rebuilding every time there's a new message added in the chat. I think it's because of the StreamBuilder. Is there an alternative for StreamBuilder?

There's a feature in the chat that a user can send a voice message. The problem is the voice message stops playing when there's a new message arrived in chat. And my observation is, I think it is caused by rebuilding the widget.

--Please excuse my poor english

Here's my code.

```
 PublishSubject<DocumentSnapshot> _chatItemsSnapshotSubject = PublishSubject();
  Stream<DocumentSnapshot> get _chatItemsStream =>
      _chatItemsSnapshotSubject.stream;

@override
void initState(){
  _db
        .collection('groupchats')
        .document(globals.groupSelected)
        .collection('messages')
        .orderBy('created_at', descending: true)
        .limit(20)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((onData) {
        _chatItemsSnapshot = onData.documents;
        onData.documents.forEach((snapshots) {
          _chatItemsSnapshotSubject.add(snapshots);
        });
    });

}

//code inside build()
StreamBuilder(
  stream: _chatItemsStream,
  builder: ((context,AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
     if(!snapshot.hasData){
        return Center(
            child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text("Loading...",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                          )
                        ],
                      )
        );
      }
      return ListView.builder(
        controller: _chatScrollController,
        itemCount: _chatItemsSnapshot.length,
        reverse: true,
        itemBuilder: (context,index){
           return ListItemWidget();
        }
      )


  })
)
```

Comment: can you please share the code ?

Comment: Can you update the question with a code so that readers can help you by knowing what you have done so far and please check here for how to ask the question on stack overflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: do you have a setstate inside a snapshot callback? Please add some code.

Comment: I already edit my post. I hope you can understand what I'm telling.

Comment: I am not sure if you intentionally wrote it but your code inside build the builder's parameter is DocuentSnapshot shouldn't it be DocumentSnapshot ?

Comment: @Patrick typo error. sorry

Comment: this problem is related with the stream, try to make the stream one and initialize it once inside initState(), whenever the stream changes page rebuilds its inevitable.

Comment: this problem is related with the stream, try to make the stream one and initialize it once inside initState(), whenever the stream changes page rebuilds its inevitable.

Comment: @Patrick I tried that but still the same.

Comment: @coffeelappy found some sol for this?